# Custom Markers in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers

[image]I have a jsonObject full of supermarkets and I would like to map them and assign them a special marker depending on the name attribute. I have tried out a lot and also the Leaflet tutorial on custom markers. Now I am asking you for help, because it didn't work.

Here is an example of my data.

```
var jsonDataObject =       
[{
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.7789009,
               "lng" : 7.188321999999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.78056527989272,
                  "lng" : 7.190323029892721
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.77786562010728,
                  "lng" : 7.187623370107278
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "990bd753b22b7499de64d1b0892717bf7b8d822d",
         "name" : "real",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4160,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/105059199501518385852\"\u003eA Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAMylhmOscrhf9ZYfOmMxV6cAivc_WjIEE33ounFMueoAJEsUzeWfR9hQNr688UxQ96GDvGBAumd_j7rRWHsVccsL9zKfSWYyperUHcXG85pr4xjSV1SiDQ1CXF4bN7HNAEhDq8EEDy52jBNsQCtKD2ucaGhTbljJSFy9RLe2Lsirr-aAAlc8XHw",
               "width" : 2336
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJh2CWukPnvkcR3gJ3XOmLpBQ",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "Q5HQ+H8 Sankt Augustin",
            "global_code" : "9F29Q5HQ+H8"
         },
         "rating" : 4.1,
         "reference" : "ChIJh2CWukPnvkcR3gJ3XOmLpBQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "supermarket",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 1784,
         "vicinity" : "Rathausallee 16, Sankt Augustin"
      }
      ];
```

And here is the code I wrote myself with recommendations.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([50.922082,6.944733], 13);


var markerIcons = {
  "REWE": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Kaufland": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Netto Filiale": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'netto.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "REWE Rahmati": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Lidl": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'lidl.jpg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "ALDI SÜD": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'aldi.jpg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "PENNY": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'penny.jpg',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "dm-drogerie markt": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Hit": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "HIT Handelsgruppe GmbH & Co. KG": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Hit getränkemarkt": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Hit Markt": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
   "Kaufland Köln-Niehl": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
"Kaufland Köln-Ehrenfeld": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Kaufland Köln-Kalk": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Kaufland Köln-Mühlheim": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "NORMA Filiale": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "NORMA": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "real": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Wodarz Getränkemarkt": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Center Engels Marsdorf GmbH": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Engels": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Peters": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Gans": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Daub KG": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Center Engels Widdersdorf": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Romano": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Wodarz": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Kausemann": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Weiden": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
"EDEKA Hein": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Feldmann-Höner": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA - Die Kippings": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Blomeier": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Aktiv Markt Hetzenegger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA STEFFENS": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Jung": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Markt Hein": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Frischmarkt Zickuhr": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Stahl": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Klein": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Hetzenegger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA-Markt Frischecenter J. Engels GbR": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Geurtz": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Wünsch": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Hetzenegger Getränkemarkt": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Klein Hessling": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Breuer": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Höner": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Schröder": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA FrischeCenter Gusek": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Zickuhr": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "EDEKA Köln-Merheim": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
  "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Klein-Heßling": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Mülln": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Bonus": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "EDEKA Breidohr-Frischecenter": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
    "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'dm.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
  }),
};



for (var i = 0; i < jsonDataObject.length; i++) {
  var lat = parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].geometry.location.lat);
  var lng = parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].geometry.location.lng);
  var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(lat, lng), {
  icon: markerIcons[jsonDataObject[i].name]
  });


marker.bindPopup(jsonDataObject[i].name, {
    autoClose: false
  });
  map.addLayer(marker);
  marker.myJsonData = jsonDataObject[i];
};


L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

Now the map shows the icons, but I want that the Icons change depending on the "name" attribute.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work at all? Errors in the console? It didn't behave as you expected? How did it behave and how do you want it to behave? Please edit your question and tell a bit more about your problems.

Comment: @TomazicM done.

Comment: You wrote "but I want that the Icons change depending on the name attribute". Change how? What do you want to change? If you divide you data into several categories, you need one icon for each category.  In your code there is only one icon. Please include all relevant info. You know what you want, but if you don't tell it, it's impossible to give you implementation advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have separate icon for each `name` property value that appears in your JSON data.

When creating `L.marker` marker, you can use `icon` option to specify custom icon for this marker. If you have separate icon for each `name` property value, you can create JSON object where properties are `name` values and where property value is corresponding icon:

```
var markerIcons = {
  "name1": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'icon1.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'shadow1.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
  }),
  "name2": L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'icon2.png',
    iconSize: [38, 95],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
    shadowUrl: 'shadow2.png',
    shadowSize: [68, 95],
    shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
  }),
.
.
. 
};
```

It's then easy to attach required icon to the marker:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonDataObject.length; i++) {
  var lat = parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].geometry.location.lat);
  var lng = parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].geometry.location.lng))
  var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(lat, lng), {
    icon: markerIcons[jsonDataObject[i].name]
  });
  marker.bindPopup(jsonDataObject[i].name, {
    autoClose: false
  });
  map.addLayer(marker);
  marker.myJsonData = jsonDataObject[i];
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for my script. Can some one tell me why? I have changed my code to this, als Tomazic recommened

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you tried and didn't work.

Comment: i have changed it.

Comment: Your new code is OK as far as code is concerned, but your icon names are wrong as far as data is concerned. All your shops have `name` property `'Lidl'`, but your `markerIcons` object contains only two icons with names `'REWE'` and `'Netto Filliale'`, but no icon for `'Lidl'`. If you look at the debugger console, you'll see error: `Unable to get property 'createIcon' of undefined or null reference`. For each name appearing in GeoJSON you have to create one icon.

Comment: I have edited the names. still not working. here my code above

Answer (score 0):

Iowa State has some great task sheets you might want to look at.

Put Leaflet in the search.
https://www.extension.iastate.edu/communities/gis/quicktasksheets

This one uses FontAwesome icons, this page has a download link to the two page instruction sheet.
https://store.extension.iastate.edu/product/15650

Or you can check out the plug in option. 
https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers